# Can I use __shfl_down on managedCUDA

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, cuda, reduction

Can I use __shfl__down on managedCUDA?

I wrote the code.

`val += __shfl_down(val, offset);`

However error massage was shown.

21  error : identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined

Comment: `__shfl_down` is compute capability 3.0 and above. Check the CC of your GPU.

Comment: You also need to compile with the -arch flag. If compute capability is more than 3.0.  e.g. nvcc -arch=sm_52 foo.cu